# Use "i" in a for loop to apply function to certain columns

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I am using for (i in cols) to loop through a list cols = c("x", "y", "z"), however:

1. when using the ":=" to create new columns, I cannot get "i" work as the name of the column
2. I created mode_func to get the most frequent string in a vector, but when I use lapply, "i" doesn't seem to serve as a column.

Can someone kindly help me understand the problem and the dynamics of "i" in a for-loop? Many thanks!

```r
set.seed(10)
dummy = data.table(id = c("11", "11", "11", "22", "22", "22", "33", "33", "33", "33"),
                   x = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = T),
                   y = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = T),
                   z = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = T),
                   i = sample(3, 10, replace = T),
                   j = sample(3, 10, replace = T),
                   k = sample(3, 10, replace = T))
mode_func <- function(x) {
  uniqx <- unique(na.omit(x))
  uniqx[which.max(tabulate(match(x, uniqx)))]
}
```

(1) Most frequent

```r
cols = c("x", "y", "z")
for (i in cols){
  dummy[, as.character(i) := mode_func(i), by = "id"]
}

# The following works but it's too much coding!
dummy[, x := mode_func(x), by = "id"]
dummy[, y := mode_func(y), by = "id"]
dummy[, z := mode_func(z), by = "id"]
```

The expected result looks like this:

```r
    id x y z
 1: 11 b b c
 2: 11 b b c
 3: 11 b b c
 4: 22 a b b
 5: 22 a b b
 6: 22 a b b
 7: 33 a a c
 8: 33 a a c
 9: 33 a a c
10: 33 a a c
```

(2) I also tried the average and this didn't work for me:

```
cols = c("i", "j", "k")
dummy[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) round(mean(x, na.rm = T))), .SDcols = cols, by = "id"]
```

Comment: In order to run your loop you could do `for (i in cols) dummy[, (i) := mode_func(.SD), .SDcols = i, by = id]`. Regarding the error in your second attempt its just type mismatch. Your code is fine but you are trying to override an integer column with a double by group. So there is a stage when part of the column is still an integer (1, 2, 3) and part of it becomes double (e.g., 2.5) and R can't have a single column with two classes. You can illustrate this by creating new columns instead, e.g., `dummy[, paste0(cols, "_mean") := lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = cols, by = id]`

Comment: You should also be careful when using column name as indexes, it make an environments mess. You both have a column called `i` and you also running your loop over `i`. This will mess up functions such as `mget/get`. So if you replace `i` with lets say `a`, you could also do `for (a in cols) dummy[, (a) := mode_func(get(a)), by = id]`. There reason you can't just run `mode_func(i)` is because data.table does non-standard evaluation in j and hence it expect column names to be unquoted- e.g. `i` instead `"i"`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail explanation and solutions!
Have a nice day, regards from Barcelona :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly call `mode_func` on `cols` using `lapply`

```
library(data.table)
dummy[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, mode_func), by = "id"]

dummy
#    id x y z
# 1: 11 b b c
# 2: 11 b b c
# 3: 11 b b c
# 4: 22 a b b
# 5: 22 a b b
# 6: 22 a b b
# 7: 33 a a c
# 8: 33 a a c
# 9: 33 a a c
#10: 33 a a c
```

---

As far as running your `for` loop is concerned, as you are calling `mode_func` function separately for each column you need to subset that particular column using `.SDcols` and pass `.SD` value as input to the function for each iteration. (Thanks to comment from @David Arenburg)

```
for (i in cols){
   dummy[, (i) := mode_func(.SD), by = "id", .SDcols = i]
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked nicely, however, I'm eager to understand how "i" interacts inside a for loop.
Btw, I've tried also to average some columns using similar way you provided, can you help me with the error I got? I included new columns i, j, k in the dummy table. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @ThomasSun David has very well explained (in comments) what is the issue with your attempt of `for` loop. He also has explained regarding your second attempt. Assuming you have numeric columns you could just create new columns to store them.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate_at` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dummy %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(cols), mode_func)
```